# How can I filter a MongoDB entry to update it using updateOne on PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to update an entry on MongoDB using the code below. I want it so that it updates the 'name' field pertaining to the studentid posted from the html form. I keep getting a syntax error for unexpected ) even though I have changed it around a lot to no avail. I got this code straight from the MongoDB documentation too?

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php' ;
$client = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');
$db_name = 'studentsinfo';
$db = $client->$db_name;
$collection = $db->students;

if($_POST)
{
  $update = $collection->updateOne([
  'studentid'=> $_POST['studentid'],
   [ '$set' => [ 'name' => 'Brunos on Astoria' ]]
  
);
}
```

Comment: what is the syntax error exactly?

Comment: @MarcelloPerri unexpected ')' expecting ']' , but when I change the bracket then it throws another one expecting ')' or ',' to the point where it is a never-ending loop

Comment: please see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing square bracket `]` in your `updateOne` method:

```
if($_POST){
     $update = $collection->updateOne(
     ['studentid'=> $_POST['studentid']],
     [ '$set' => [ 'name' => 'Brunos on Astoria' ]]
     );
}
```

Comment: Now, it is saying Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function updateOne(), 1 passed, and at least 2 expected

Comment: we are going somewhere then, what is `$set` in your code?

Comment: actually, there are too many brackets in your code, I have updated the answer, have a look now please.

Comment: I was just taking a look at that. I am not sure what that is. I assumed it was a reserve word or function? because I have no $set variable. I copied it directly from https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.7/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-updateOne/

Comment: have a look now